# How to use LAG to shift a column value down one partition?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Look at the example table:

| Name | Places | Date | Quarter | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | XYZ | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 30 |
| ABC | XYZ | 02-01-2021 | 1 | 20 |
| ABC | XYZ | 03-01-2021 | 1 | 5 |
| ABC | XYZ | 04-01-2021 | 2 | 80 |

From this table, I created a RUNNING_TOTAL column partitioned by Name, Places and Quarter.

| Name | Places | Date | Quarter | Cost | Running Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | XYZ | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 30 | 55 |
| ABC | XYZ | 02-01-2021 | 1 | 20 | 55 |
| ABC | XYZ | 03-01-2021 | 1 | 5 | 55 |
| ABC | XYZ | 04-01-2021 | 2 | 80 | 80 |

What I'm trying to do now is shift the running total column down for that group, to have sort of a "Previous Running Total" value, as below:

| Name | Places | Date | Quarter | Cost | Running Total | Previous RT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | XYZ | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 30 | 30 | NULL |
| ABC | XYZ | 02-01-2021 | 1 | 20 | 50 | NULL |
| ABC | XYZ | 03-01-2021 | 1 | 5 | 55 | NULL |
| ABC | XYZ | 04-01-2021 | 2 | 80 | 80 | 55 |

I've tried to partition the exact same way I partition my RUNNING_TOTAL column:

```
LAG(RUNNING_TOTAL) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME, PLACES, QUARTER ORDER BY NAME, PLACES, QUARTER) AS PREVIOUS_RT
```

As you can imagine, this is not working and the result I'm getting is:

| Name | Places | Date | Quarter | Cost | Running Total | Previous RT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | XYZ | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 30 | 30 | NULL |
| ABC | XYZ | 02-01-2021 | 1 | 20 | 50 | 55 |
| ABC | XYZ | 03-01-2021 | 1 | 5 | 55 | 55 |
| ABC | XYZ | 04-01-2021 | 2 | 80 | 80 | 55 |

Any help on how to achieve the desired result is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add a rownumber for each group and only show it when its 1 (a group change) otherwise null

Comment: @JorgeCampos I'm not sure I'm following, can you perhaps post your attempt?

Comment: Someone already beat me to it! I was in my phone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the analytic `SUM` function with a `RANGE` window:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       SUM(cost) OVER (
         PARTITION BY name, places, quarter
         ORDER BY Date_column
       ) AS q_total,         
       SUM(cost) OVER (
         PARTITION BY name, places
         ORDER BY quarter
         RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
       ) AS prev_q_total
FROM   table_name t
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Name, Places, Date_Column, Quarter, Cost) AS
SELECT 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2021-01-01', 1, 30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2021-01-02', 1, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2021-01-03', 1,  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2021-01-04', 2, 80 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| NAME | PLACES | DATE_COLUMN | QUARTER | COST | Q_TOTAL | PREV_Q_TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | XYZ | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 30 | 30 | *null* |
| ABC | XYZ | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 1 | 20 | 50 | *null* |
| ABC | XYZ | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 1 | 5 | 55 | *null* |
| ABC | XYZ | 2021-01-04 00:00:00 | 2 | 80 | 80 | 55 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ScGAysfA)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the previous running total to not take into account the quarter as you shown in your example:

```
select name, places, dat, quarter, cost, running_total,
 lag(running_total) over(partition by name, places order by dat) as prev_running_total
from (
    select name, places, dat, quarter, cost, sum(cost) over(partition by name, places, quarter order by dat) as running_total
    from data 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like here:

```
WITH    --  Sample Data
    tbl(A_NAME, PLACES, A_DATE, QUARTER, A_COST) AS
        (
            Select 'ABC',   'XYZ', To_Date('01-01-2021', 'mm-dd-yyyy'), 1,  30 From Dual Union All
            Select 'ABC',   'XYZ', To_Date('02-01-2021', 'mm-dd-yyyy'), 1,  20 From Dual Union All
            Select 'ABC',   'XYZ', To_Date('03-01-2021', 'mm-dd-yyyy'), 1,   5 From Dual Union All
            Select 'ABC',   'XYZ', To_Date('04-01-2021', 'mm-dd-yyyy'), 2,  80 From Dual 
        )

M a i n   S Q L :
SELECT    A_NAME, PLACES, A_DATE, QUARTER, A_COST, Q_RUNING_TOTAL,
          CASE  WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By A_NAME, PLACES, QUARTER Order By A_NAME, PLACES, QUARTER) = 1 And
                     Nvl(LAG(Q_RUNING_TOTAL) OVER(Order By A_NAME, PLACES, QUARTER), 0) != 0
                THEN Nvl(LAG(Q_RUNING_TOTAL) OVER(Order By A_NAME, PLACES, QUARTER), 0) 
          END "PREV_Q_RT"
FROM    ( Select    A_NAME, PLACES, A_DATE, QUARTER, A_COST, 
                    Sum(A_COST) OVER(Partition By A_NAME, PLACES, QUARTER Order By A_NAME, PLACES, QUARTER Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) "Q_RUNING_TOTAL"
          From  tbl )
ORDER BY A_NAME, PLACES, A_DATE

R e s u l t :
A_NAME PLACES A_DATE       QUARTER     A_COST Q_RUNING_TOTAL  PREV_Q_RT
------ ------ --------- ---------- ---------- -------------- ----------
ABC    XYZ    01-JAN-21          1         30             30            
ABC    XYZ    01-FEB-21          1         20             50            
ABC    XYZ    01-MAR-21          1          5             55            
ABC    XYZ    01-APR-21          2         80             80         55
```

The above code will show prrevious quorter total only in first row of the actual quarter. If there are more data and if you want the previous quarter in every row of the current one then see the sample  data and code below:

```sql
WITH    --  Sample Data
    tbl(A_NAME, PLACES, A_DATE, QUARTER, A_COST) AS
        (
            Select 'ABC',   'XYZ', To_Date('01-01-2021', 'mm-dd-yyyy'), 1,  30 From Dual Union All
            Select 'ABC',   'XYZ', To_Date('02-01-2021', 'mm-dd-yyyy'), 1,  20 From Dual Union All
            Select 'ABC',   'XYZ', To_Date('03-01-2021', 'mm-dd-yyyy'), 1,   5 From Dual Union All
            --
            Select 'ABC',   'XYZ', To_Date('04-01-2021', 'mm-dd-yyyy'), 2,   5 From Dual Union All
            Select 'ABC',   'XYZ', To_Date('05-01-2021', 'mm-dd-yyyy'), 2,  35 From Dual Union All
            Select 'ABC',   'XYZ', To_Date('06-01-2021', 'mm-dd-yyyy'), 2,  80 From Dual 
        )

M a i n   S Q L :
SELECT    t.A_NAME, t.PLACES, t.A_DATE, t.QUARTER, t.A_COST, t.Q_RUNING_TOTAL,
          CASE  WHEN (PREV_Q = To_Char(ADD_MONTHS(A_DATE, -3), 'Q/yyyy')) 
                THEN ( Select Sum(A_COST) From tbl WHERE A_NAME = t.A_NAME And PLACES = t.PLACES And To_Char(A_DATE, 'Q/yyyy') = t.PREV_Q ) 
          END "PREV_Q_RT"
FROM    ( Select    A_NAME, PLACES, A_DATE, QUARTER, A_COST, 
                    Sum(A_COST) OVER(Partition By A_NAME, PLACES, QUARTER Order By A_NAME, PLACES, QUARTER Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) "Q_RUNING_TOTAL",
                    To_Char(ADD_MONTHS(A_DATE, -3), 'Q/yyyy') "PREV_Q" 
          From  tbl ) t
ORDER BY A_NAME, PLACES, A_DATE

R e s u l t :
A_NAME PLACES A_DATE       QUARTER     A_COST Q_RUNING_TOTAL  PREV_Q_RT
------ ------ --------- ---------- ---------- -------------- ----------
ABC    XYZ    01-JAN-21          1         30             30            
ABC    XYZ    01-FEB-21          1         20             50            
ABC    XYZ    01-MAR-21          1          5             55            
ABC    XYZ    01-APR-21          2          5              5         55 
ABC    XYZ    01-MAY-21          2         35             40         55 
ABC    XYZ    01-JUN-21          2         80            120         55
```

This one should work across years too (the first does not).